# Test Failures were logged

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Version. I am creating a function using an API call.

Whenever I run Unit Test for that function, the function is executed but after the completion of the test, I get a test failure message with "91 test failures were logged" message. The rest of my tests work fine.

> [image: This is the snapshot of what I get on completion of Test]

Any probable solution or any leads?

Comment: You may want to indicate what testing framework you are using. If you don't know, it's likely MSTest. It might help visibility if you added a tag with the appropriate test framework.

Comment: Please post the code for both the function and the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was some Project issue. I restarted Visual Studio and built each of the projects individually and the problem is gone.